# Localizable text in custom layout?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm customizing Display Suite-suggested tpl by adding "Jump to top" links at the bottom of each teaser and I want to properly localize the link text.

Now I am unclear as per the usability of the Variable module (that had to be installed along with i18n). Can I add my own variable (say, jump_to_top_link) somewhere in the Variable admin panel, without writing my own module? Or is Variable meant only as an API for modules?

I don't want to learn module development now, but I want my custom text to be scalable and easily manageable from one place, instead of hard-coding strings and ifs.

Would anyone be willing to shed light on how to approach the problem?

Regards,
Artur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the translations for each specified language in the strings settings part of the internationalization module: /admin/config/regional/i18n_translation

To show it in a template file you simply use the t() function to wrap your text - which translates text for you and automatically adds new text defined in the t() function to the strings page.

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/t/7

If you are hardcoding links with your text you can use l(), so if you have say a text link and want the text to be translated you would use l() and in it define your text using t() - something like this:  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/t/7

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/7 for its usage.

Comment: Thank you, but where do I actually add the variable? Nowhere in the admin did I find a link like "Add variable" :(

Comment: You do not 'add' it via the admin panel. Drupal will find it once you add text to the .tpl file or in a module using the t() function and subsequently call that page tpl or module. For example, I downloaded a new theme, edited the page--front.tpl.php file and somewhere in its body I added <?php print t('this is a test translation of whuphup');?>. I load the front page after clearing my cache - then I go to admin/config/regional/translate/translate or Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface and my text wrapped in the t() function will show up there.

Comment: If it doesn't, try searching, and then it should show up. From there I can add translations for each language and anywhere that string is present it will be translated depending on the users language etc ..

Comment: O holy... :) That's so sneaky and smart of Drupal! Thank you so much for your kind help!